# I am try to make this code work in Visual Studio 2010 and it says my "SWFObject is undefined" in the firefox brower. And the swfobject.js is a 2.2 

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, flash, swfobject

I am trying to make this code work in Visual Studio 2010 and it says my "SWFObject is undefined" in the firefox brower. And the swfobject.js is a v2.2 .I want the .swf in the "gs" div to play first and then play the other .swf in the "billboard" div, when the "gs" .swf is finish playing or clicked off. So that the .swfs don't play at the same time and are slow.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(readCookie("flashPlayed") == "true"){
        showWater();
    }
});

function launchFlash(){
    if(readCookie("flashPlayed") != "true"){
 var homeflash = new SWFObject("/Content/swf/2BigGS.swf", "BG", "1003", "840", "8");
homeflash.addParam("wmode","transparent");
homeflash.write("gs");
setTimeout("showWater()", 33000);
setTimeout("removeFlash()", 33000);
    }
}

function readCookie(cookieName){
    var searchName = cookieName + "="
    var cookies = document.cookie
    var start = cookies.indexOf(cookieName)
    if (start == -1){ // cookie not found 
        return ""
    }
    start += searchName.length //start of the cookie data
    var end = cookies.indexOf(";", start)
    if (end == -1){
        end = cookies.length
    }
    return cookies.substring(start, end)
}

function showwater(){
    $("#billboard").fadeIn("slow");
    document.cookie="flashPlayed=true"
}
function removeFlash(){
    $("#gs").empty();
    $("#gs").animate( { top:"-9999px"}, 1 )
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

SWFObject 2 has an entirely different API from 1.5 - it doesn't define anything named "SWFObject" - and also doesn't use a constructor function.

One way of using it:

```
var flashvars = null;
var params = { "wmode": "transparent" };
var attributes = null;
swfobject.embedSWF(
   "/Content/swf/2BigGS.swf", "BG", "1003", "840", "8", false, 
   flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Also be aware that version 2 *replaces* the element you specify for swf insertion, i.e.:

In version 1.5:

```
<div id="gs"></div>
```

became:

```
<div id="gs"><object id="BG">...</object></div>
```

In version 2.0:

```
<div id="gs"><div id="BG"></div></div>
```

becomes:

```
<div id="gs"><object id="BG">...</object></div>
```

I.e., a "BG" element must already be there - it's replaced, rather than inserted.

This may mean that you need to change other parts of the code. For example, you can't check if the swf has been inserted by checking for an element with the `id` "BG", because BG is still there (as a `<div>` in the above example) even if inserting the swf failed.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation